# Measure execution time forth

Tags: forth, gforth

How to measure execution time of my program? I`ve found this but it doesnot work for me because my program needs some numbers in stack to work so my program and this solution kind of interfiering with each other(as I understand because when i try `time: myfunc` or `time: num1 num2 myfunc` nothing works....)

```
: time: ( "word" -- )
  utime 2>R ' EXECUTE
  utime 2R> D-
  <# # # # # # # [CHAR] . HOLD #S #> TYPE ."  seconds" ;
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 6):

The tick `'` will parse the text immediately following the call to `time:`. So for a call with arguments it should be `num1 num2 time: myfunc`

Also, the tick will parse the input stream in run time. If you have the call to `time:` embedded in the word definition, it will try to get the execution toke for the word from the input stream, not for the word immediately following the `time:`. Use `[']` to get an `xt` of the next word in compile time, and pass that `xt` as argument to `time:`

```
: time ( xt -- )
  utime 2>R EXECUTE
  utime 2R> D-
  <# # # # # # # [CHAR] . HOLD #S #> TYPE ."  seconds" ;

: foo 0 1000000 0 do i + loop drop ;

: bar num1 num2 ['] foo time ; \ pass the foo's xt as argument to time
```

Note there's no `'` call in `time`, the `EXECUTE` will grab the token from the stack.